# Bl lu ur rr ry yv vi is si io on - Blur the text

Tags: code-golf, string

## Task

Given a string as input, generate a "blurred" version of that string.

## Input

Your input will be a single-line string of ASCII characters, containing a minimum of 2 alphanumeric characters

## Output

A string that is the "blurred" version of the input string.

A blurred string is one where every alphanumeric character from the original string has been paired with the ones adjacent to it, and each pair is separated by a space.

Any non-alphanumeric characters (whitespace, puncuation) in the input string must be ignored when determining adjacency of alphanumeric characters, and they must not included in the blurred string.

There must be no leading or trailing whitespace in the output string.

## Examples

`Ab` -> `Ab`
`Abc` -> `Ab bc`
`Abcd` -> `Ab bc cd`
`E?h?` -> `Eh`
`Blurry vision` -> `Bl lu ur rr ry yv vi is si io on`
`We're #1!` -> `We er re e1`
`I'm an example!` -> `Im ma an ne ex xa am mp pl le`
`This is _not_ legible` -> `Th hi is si is sn no ot tl le eg gi ib bl le`
`(a*b*c)+5^-x` -> `ab bc c5 5x`
`??a_%,1!=z#@` -> `a1 1z`

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so fewest bytes wins!

Comment: The non-alphanumeric characters _have_ to be ignored or _can_ be ignored?

Comment: @RGS Thanks for the clarification question, non-alphanumeric characters _must_ be ignored

Comment: Might the input contain the character `_`? If so, would we need to explicitly ignore it?

Comment: I would suggest to add test cases with “*leading-non-alphanumeric” and “multiple<=>non<=>alphanumeric”.

Comment: @mathjunkie Correct, the input may contain `_` and it must be ignored

Comment: I feel like this challenge suffers from a lot of poorly motivated add-ons.  For example removing certain characters from the string, or requiring no trailing whitespace.  These additions don't really have a reason to exist or an internal logic, they just get in the way of writing an answer.  I started to write an answer but found these extra conditions inflated my code by nearly three times, making them actually the bulk of the challenge.

Comment: Here are some posts [1](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8077/56656) [2](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8214/56656) where you can read more about why I disagree with these extraneous elements.

Comment: What characters qualify as whitespace?

Comment: Why no trailing whitespace? Why do we have to ignore non-alphanumeric characters? These just seem like a lot of extra requirements that make the challenge less fun.

Comment: In future it's best to post questions to meta so the kinks can be worked out to give a question that is more about the essence of problem solving, than handling edge cases

Comment: Totally agreeing with @AdHocGarfHunter, I started to write a solution in BF and then realized that checking for allowed characters will probably inflate the solution by factor 4 or 5. This probably could be a different challenge "Only print numbers and characters from a string".

Comment: @S.S.Anne, bucause without it it would be too simple. The only thing I'm surprised with is ignoring `_` as it adds at least 3 chars to regex-based solutions and has no additional value. Maybe this point should've been left unspecified.

Answer (score 25):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>57</s> 55 bytes

```python
lambda s:"".join((c+" "+c)*c.isalnum()for c in s)[2:-2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PVBda8IwFH3PrzirjLV@FLrhi1A7Bz74PtjD5iSt0WakaUiitIq/3d10MAiXe8/HvZyY3tetfrkf8q@74k2553CLKEp/WqnjuJpEiCZVMq5S6bjSpyZODq1FBanhks/nxex5e5eNaa2H6x1jgVVSi0HQu9T5vdQLBrgpuHbI0XATO2@JsdJMB3HqjJI@jmbLKElIa0l2iF1ojZXax4fo6m6YLXG1N3xebZ7Trts2Su6rMsCrkq3K6q9DWYVh/z@h2rN1URcBWNfsTZ2s7XGWTrY6YG8K6oSThaXXoz8TB@ngqLZoNfsQT1ZglD0E9YeAIB3VjG2eGgoF0fHGKDHQm4YCBpC@QHToqCfEwNARwd5r2ktvp1u/I@AoSyWC7b1G/X@UKvnptIcPNogjjoRTmGFLzMfluEom8@9ZF8z8L@Uc844VBd89TrOH/DJ6HbgM2eUX)

**How**:

- For each alpha-numeric character `c` in the string, replace it with `c+" "+c`.
  E.g: `"abcd" -> "a ab bc cd d"`
- Remove the redundant first and last 2 characters:
  E.g: `"a ab bc cd d" -> "ab bc cd"`

Comment: I like this answer because it's elegant, and, esoterically, very useful. I might use this if I, for some reason, decide to add bluriness (how do you even type that?) to some program.

Comment: @mazunki bl lu ur rr ri in ne es ss

Answer (score 13):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5 bytes

```
wX2f□
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/vzzCKO3RtIX///9X0kjUStJK1tQ2jdOtUAIA)

## Explanation

```
   f   Keep all items that
    □  Is an alphanumeric character.
 X     Pick all sublists
  2    With a length of 2.
w      Join the output list by spaces.
```

Answer (score 8):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>27 24 22</s> 21 bytes

```
" "/2':(2!"/9@Z`z"')_
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k#eJy9kk1Lw0AQhu/5FW8XIUlFCoUcTA7WQg+9e7LEZFPzRfPFJikbRX+771oUz1KyDLPDu8s8M8NkvoBYrW3fWS/E6n7zHL8J240sa/Dfbw7Tp/Iz6CBuT4ETZ7KsAh1MgXLDD2s4iMdEhMZh1nMhH7/R4D07+fUHDYbzkXfFA8G7Yt5xG/K2GpWacC77sm1Yw7ZCNWJUULQJ05lPKHv09C345WrkvV1DNki1rLsqXZC9r1FLozUpZWjGVDp0rCm90mgM+algQ7SoaYeIqfMyYf6QOorfZulZCFseMBg+0hw5dS7H/8oxZEcuk+XRvfVe7jSB8rJpHjz9N98XjjmwXw==)

`` "/9@Z`z"' `` binary search in the given string

`2!` mod 2

`` (2!"/9@Z`z"')_ `` drop non-alphanumeric chars

`2':` make a list of pairs of adjacent chars

`" "/` join with spaces

Answer (score 8):

## [sed] -E (C locale), <sup><s>46</s> <s>33</s></sup> 23 bytes

```bash
s/\W|_//g;s/\B.\B/& &/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7BSsNAFEX37ytuU221GkMXrmwSkxJBKLgRuikOk@SZDKRJmBk1Sv89HQoSeFwe98Dl5NLUYyEtoshwKUyhVW@x2XjZ24s3muCwP4kgqJ7clz4c0mCBRVCNDhLx0HfaYrcVyW4Xbol@atUwNMsSlo1tVMsElJ0LgIu6g9/Cu/pnCCN4E5uAhxOcDPwM/icmrcuY2xyTHJTkxSVKUBbXMShtvrT@xbcyqmtBe15qxnw9A70uj5AteJDHvmFXvNfKwJ1oOyvQcKVyJ043cpWvitu7xw9/AMWxFNf361n4N3@mMw)

*Thanks to pizzapants184 for a 13-byte improvement.*

*10 more bytes off thanks to Dom Hastings.*

---

Input on stdin, and output on stdout.

If your locale isn't set to C, you can set it with: `export LC_ALL=C`

Comment: I think you can replace `s/\B(.)\B/\1\1 /g;s/(.) / \1/g` with `s/\B(.)\B/\1 \1/g` for [33 bytes](https://tio.run/##RY5dS4RAGIXv319x1i32oybzooto1dzFYEHoJugiWxl10gFXZWYqW/rvNiyE8HIu3udweHKu67HgBkGgRZnpQsneYLNx4ucnZ9Tu2@GW3XN2enfdav@g3XS7vFmlWzf1kHpuNdoakRj6ThkkuyxKEn9H9F3LRkAJXsIIbRrZCgLKzgYgiroDa@Fc/DP4AZyJTcDBL6wWWAz2gUnwPGY3xygHRXlxjhIUh3UI2jafSv3gS2rZtaBXsVACc28G2i@O4C3EwI99I@zjpZYa9rK2MxkaUcncitOSr/N1sbq6O7ABFIY8u7z2Zv5p/kh/ "Bash – Try It Online")

Comment: @pizzapants184 Thank you -- I thought I had tried that :) .

Comment: You can drop this to 23 bytes with a couple of minor tweaks: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7BSsNAFEX37ytuU221GkMXrmwSkxJBKLgRuikOk@SZDKRJmBk1Sv89HQoSeFwe98Dl5NLUYyEtoshwKUyhVW@x2XjZ24s3muCwP4kgqJ7clz4c0mCBRVCNDhLx0HfaYrcVyW4Xbol@atUwNMsSlo1tVMsElJ0LgIu6g9/Cu/pnCCN4E5uAhxOcDPwM/icmrcuY2xyTHJTkxSVKUBbXMShtvrT@xbcyqmtBe15qxnw9A70uj5AteJDHvmFXvNfKwJ1oOyvQcKVyJ043cpWvitu7xw9/AMWxFNf361n4N3@mMw "Bash – Try It Online")

Comment: It's almost a polyglot with Perl too, if the replacement string is `$& $&` instead of `& &`!

Comment: @DomHastings Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 14 bytes

```
jd.::Q"\W|_"k2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PytFz8oqUCkmvCZeKdvo/3@lkIzMYgUgis/LL4lXyElNz0zKSVUCAA)

- `:Q"\W|_"k` replaces each non-alphanumeric character of the input with the empty string by matching each character against the regex `\W|_`
- `.: --- 2` finds all substrings of length 2
- `jd` joins the substrings using spaces

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>8</s> <s>7</s> 8 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to @CommandMaster*

*+1 byte again thanks to @KevinCruijssen finding an issue*

```
žKÃüJðý?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6D7vw82H93gd3nB4r/3///b2ifGqOoaKtlXKDgA)

Comment: 7 bytes: `žKÃüJðý`

Comment: You forgot a trailing `?`, since the challenge disallows a trailing newline (for whatever stupid reason..)

Comment: Solid gravedigging @KevinCruijssen, I've updated

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
fØB;ƝK
```

A monadic Link accepting a list of characters which yields a list of characters.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/t8Awn62Nzvf///6@kkaiVpJWsqW0ap1uhBAA)**

#### How?

```
fØB;ƝK - Link: list of characters, S
 ØB    - base-62 characters = "01...89AB...YZab...yz"
f      - (S) filter keep if in (that)
    Ɲ  - for neighbours:
   ;   -   concatenate
     K - join with spaces
```

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```
t8Y2m)2YC!Z{0&Zc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v8Qi0ihX0yjSWTGq2kAtKvn/f3WnnNKiokqFsszizPw8dQA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8L/EItIoV9Mo0lkxqtpALSr5v0vIf3XHJHUuIJEMIVOAlKt9hj2QcsopLSqqVCjLLM7MzwPyw1PV1YtSFZQNFYEcT3X1XIXEPIXUisTcgpxUkFBIRmaxAhDF5@WXxCvkpKZnJuWkAsU1ErWStJI1tU3jdCuAXHv7xHhVHUNF2yplB3UA).

#### Explanation

Consider input `'Blurry vision'`.

```
t      % Implicit input. Duplicate
       % STACK: 'Blurry vision', 'Blurry vision'
8Y2    % Push '012...9ABC...Zabc...z' (predefined literal)
       % STACK: 'Blurry vision', 'Blurry vision', '012...9ABC...Zabc...z'
m      % Ismember: true for chars of the first string that are in the second
       % STACK: 'Blurry vision', [1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1]
)      % Use as logical index. This keeps only letters and numbers in the input
       % STACK: 'Blurryvision'
2YC    % Character matrix with sliding blocks of length 2 as columns
       % STACK: ['Blurryvisio';
                 'lurryvision']
!      % Transpose
       % STACK: ['Bl';
                 'lu';
                 ...
                 'on']
Z{     % Cell array of matrix rows
       % STACK: {'Bl' 'lu ... 'on'}
0&Zc   % Join with character 0 (which will be displayed as space)
       % STACK: 'Bl lu ur rr ry yv vi is si io on'
       % Implicit display
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to properly handle input strings that contain numbers

Comment: @mathjunkie Thanks for pointing that out. I have corrected it

Comment: Save a byte: `"@32v!`

Comment: @Sanchises Thanks! But that produces a trailing space, which is not allowed

Comment: Oh yes overlooked the overly restrictive spec

Answer (score 5):

## T<sub>E</sub>X (INIT<sub>E</sub>X), 372 bytes

```tex
\catcode`~13\let~\catcode~`{1~`}2~`#6~`\ 12~`|13\let|\expandafter\def\z{}\def\f#1{#1}\def\i#1{}\def\b#1#2{\ifx#2\e|||\i|\i\else|\f\fi{\ifcat#1a|\f\else|||\b|||#2|\i\fi}{\ifcat#2a #1#2|\b|#2\else|\b|#1\fi}}\def\t{~`011~`111~`211~`311~`411~`511~`611~`711~`811~`911~`\|12~`\~12~`\#12~`\{12~`\}12~127=12~`\%12~`\\12\read16to\x\edef\r{|\b\x\e}\immediate\write16{|\i\r\z}\end}\t
```

For example, the program being saved in a file named "codegolf.tex", provided with input `??a_%,1!=\z#@`, `initex codegolf.tex` outputs:

```
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian) (INITEX)
(./codegolf.tex
\x=??a_%,1!=\z#@
a1 1z
 )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on codegolf.log.
```

In the case of a degraded input, for example the strings `??`, `?a`, or `a?`, this implementation does not print any pair.

## Explanation

### Basis for a T<sub>E</sub>X program

```
\read16
```

Per [this Meta answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13652/94729), the input of a program written in T<sub>E</sub>X should come from standard input, which is the *in register* number 16.

```
\immediate\write16
```

The T<sub>E</sub>X Codegolf community prefers to output to DVI or PDF, because it is simpler than writing to the terminal.  However, this requires a valid `\output` routine, which either requires a format (with more category codes to alter<sup>1</sup>) or is longer to define.  So I write to the terminal. (`\message` could also have been used, but I don't like how the output is surrounded by T<sub>E</sub>X chat on the same line).

Because I output to the terminal, I also feel that no DVI file should get produced, so `\immediate` is required<sup>2</sup>.

```
\end
```

This is a complete program, so it must end with `\end` to run cleanly.

### Category codes

Running on alphanumerics and ignoring punctuation is a trivial matter for T<sub>E</sub>X.  All I have to do is to customize the category codes of those characters.

For this subject, I will use category code 11 ("letter") for characters that need to be blurred, and category code 12 ("other") for characters that are to be dropped. That choice comes from the defaults of (ini)T<sub>E</sub>X, where letters are already set to 11 and most of the other characters to 12.

```
\catcode`~13\let~\catcode
```

To save bytes, I make <kbd>~</kbd> an active character and set its meaning to `\catcode`.  In the rest of the explanation, that alias will be ungolfed.

```
\catcode`{=1 \catcode`}=2 \catcode`#=6 \catcode`\ =12
```

These are required for INIT<sub>E</sub>X to interpret my program correctly: <kbd>{</kbd> is now the begin-group character, <kbd>}</kbd> the end-group, <kbd>#</kbd> the macro argument, and <kbd>␣</kbd> is considered a normal character (so that the first spurious space of output can be removed).  These choices are widely used in the T<sub>E</sub>X world and do not cost bytes<sup>3</sup>.

```
\catcode`|=13 \let|=\expandafter
```

This is an useful alias for later.

```
\def\t{\catcode`0=11 ... \end}
\t
```

This is a T<sub>E</sub>X design pattern that fools T<sub>E</sub>X's eyes.  Everything that is written in the `\todo` macro definition will get a category code assigned, and this category code will not be reconsidered when TeX expands the macro.  Most notably:

```
\catcode`\\=12
```

This makes the escape character <kbd>\</kbd> a normal character when read from the user input.

```
\read16to\x \edef\r{|\b\x\e} \immediate\write16{|\i\r\z} \end
```

When reading the macro definition, T<sub>E</sub>X has decided that these were control words, and T<sub>E</sub>X will not reconsider this choice after the macro has been expanded, even if <kbd>\</kbd> has lost its special meaning in the meantime.

```
\catcode127=12
```

The <kbd>DEL</kbd> character is contained in ASCII, so it should be valid input per the subject's rules.  But in order to change its category code to 12, the DEL character has to be written, and the most efficient<sup>4</sup> way to input it in T<sub>E</sub>X is to name it by its code point.

```
\catcode`0=11 ... \catcode`\\=12
```

Here are three groups of category code assignments: make the digits like letters, revert the changes made at the beginning of the program, and cancel other INIT<sub>E</sub>X defaults (<kbd>DEL</kbd>, <kbd>%</kbd>, <kbd>\</kbd>, but not the new line because the subject emits the hypothesis:)

> Your input will be a single-line string

### The blurring command

Because I opted for terminal output, and because `\write` does not executes its argument (only expands it), I am forced to write the `\blur` macro as fully expandable.

```
\def\z{} \def\firstofone#1{#1} \def\ignore#1{}
```

As a prolog, I define three macros, which are commonly used in various fully-expandable design patterns.  The first one is the empty macro, the second one is the identity macro, and the third one is the zero macro.

```
\def\blur#1#2{ ... }
```

The `\blur` macro is recursive<sup>5</sup>.  It takes two characters at a time (because the rules say that the input is longer than two).  Its definition is made of three parts.

```
\ifx#2\e \expandafter\expandafter \expandafter\ignore \expandafter\ignore
\else    \expandafter\firstofone
\fi
```

is the recursion condition: if the end-of-string marker (the undefined command `\e`<sup>6</sup>) is found, ignore the two other parts. (More precisely, drop the unused portion of the conditional `\else...\fi` at `\expandafter` level 0, then ignore the second part at `\expandafter` level 1, then ignore the third part at `\expandafter` level 2.)  Otherwise, close the conditional and interpret the second part.

```
\ifcat#1a \expandafter\firstofone
\else \expandafter\expandafter \expandafter\blur
      \expandafter\expandafter \expandafter#2
      \expandafter             \ignore
\fi
```

handles the first character.  If it is a letter or digit, go analysing a second character.  Otherwise, skip the remaining of the conditional, ignore the third part, and call `\blur` recursively with #1 being dropped and #2 as the first character<sup>7</sup> (an other one will get extracted from input).

```
\ifcat#2a ␣#1#2 \expandafter\blur \expandafter#2
\else \expandafter\blur \expandafter#1
\fi
```

handles the second character.  If it is a letter or digit, output a space then the first part of the blur, then forget about #1 and call `\blur` recursively on #2<sup>7</sup>.  Otherwise, forget about it and call `\blur` recursively on #1<sup>7</sup>.

### Calling the blurring command on real input

```
\read16 to \x
```

will store the input into an (expandable) macro `\x`.

```
\expandafter\blur \x \e
```

This is how the `\blur` macro is called. Because `\blur` acts on tokens, the input contained in `\x` must be expanded first.  The end-of-string marker follows.

```
\edef\result{\expandafter\blur \x \e}
```

The result of the expansion, including the whitespace at front, is stored into the `\result` macro.

```
\expandafter\ignore \result \z
```

Inside the `\write16` command, the `\result` macro is first expanded.  Then, `\ignore` eliminates the first token of output: the first space if the output is non-empty, or the `\z` macro call if the output is empty.  In the first case, the `\z` macro will survive; but `\write16` will finally expand it, and its expansion is a no-op.  This is the most efficient way of handling the “no trailing space” requirement, even if it requires 24 bytes (the definition and call of `\z` and `\return`); suppressing a space at the end of the output would have been nearly impossible.

### ☡ Footnotes

1. <kbd>$</kbd>, <kbd>&</kbd>, <kbd>^</kbd>, <kbd>_</kbd>, <kbd>NUL</kbd>, <kbd>SPC</kbd>, <kbd>TAB</kbd>, <kbd>~</kbd> for plain T<sub>E</sub>X; 5 bytes each = 40 bytes.
2. Without `\immediate`, `\write` adds its content to a whatsit box, thus generating a page of output.
3. Because there are only three category code changes, it is not worth putting them in a group to save the reverting.
4. Decimal: `127=` (4); Hexadecimal: `"7F=` (4, harder to read); Octal: `'199=` (5); Escape sequence: ``` ``\^^? ``` (5, plus `` \catcode`^7 `` and revert)
5. It is even *tail-recursive*, which in T<sub>E</sub>X has the meaning of "it does not add tokens after the recursive call", and by doing so is more memory-friendly.
6. Because all input other than my program does not get interpreted, the `\e` command cannot be defined later.
7. This would fail if #2 was a simple group of arguments, but fortunately the input cannot contain simple groups, because no character has category code 1 nor 2.

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 13 bytes

```
\W|_

Lw| `..
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/Pya8Jp6Ly6e8RiFBT@//f6ec0iLFokqFsszizPw8AA)

### Explanation

`\W|_` Replace each character NOT in the regex group \W (which is `A-Z,a-z,0-9,_`) or a `_` with nothing

`` Lw| `.. `` Compute lists (`L`) for each set of two characters (`..`) starting at all positions in the string (`w`) and separate the lists with a space (`|` )

Comment: `$&` is the default output for `L` so no need to use `$`. (But I didn't know you could omit the `'` after `L|`.)

Comment: @Neil Thanks for the tip - first Retina answer so still learning and madly skimming the documentation!

Comment: (Technically `w` allows the match to start and end at all positions in the string while `v` only allows the longest possible matches starting at all positions. Of course it makes no difference in a case like this where there is only one possible match per position.)

Answer (score 4):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), <s>51</s> 37 bytes

-14 bytes thanks to chunes

```
[ [ alpha? ] filter 2 clump " "join ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYrNSgMxFIX38xSnU6RaUajgRpHYgkg3blRclDrcibczVzJJTDLSWvrsY0rh8J0fzoZ0cmF4f12@PN@BohZBE1zvxTaI/NOz1RzhA6e080Fswn1R7FHO6/IIfeJXtifVqmwL04eww69EcTb3D54Exng2ynk56UAWvKXOGz4ub61EZFXWpQqGG6kN5/2cpvVUX1zefl5tc1WKqrPZ6OFv/FjiUAwrrEDGt6SwxkZM4oAbaNN3Hvn@7cRiPXTkcT38Aw)

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 51 bytes

```
: b ( s -- s ) [ alpha? ] filter 2 clump " " join ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY5fS8MwFMXf9ynOOmR/JMIEXzokUxDpy15UfBizpPGuzUiTmKTSKX72mjLu5XfuOQ@HexQyWj@8vRS75xwiSKVQe9s5ZWoE@urISApwnmI8O69MxGZS7HI86s6z2BCL1MchR4UFAhhLWGIPoV0jOA44Kh3J4xZSd61DluZklcFm@EX2UGUj5IWfSZ54w5OM7f6MbxWUNcm/09wTZutpuot5C2FAvWidpjF5bVRA2tLYWEJTrSpNKV@IVbWSy@u7D9Yny7kor9bT@5/ZNsPfZJ9@PqAVDjfDPw)

Unbelievably [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) is competitive with Python and JavaScript :)

Comment: [37 bytes](https://tio.run/##JYrNSgMxFIX38xSnU6RaUajgRpHYgkg3blRclDrcibczVzJJTDLSWvrsY0rh8J0fzoZ0cmF4f12@PN@BohZBE1zvxTaI/NOz1RzhA6e080Fswn1R7FHO6/IIfeJXtifVqmwL04eww69EcTb3D54Exng2ynk56UAWvKXOGz4ub61EZFXWpQqGG6kN5/2cpvVUX1zefl5tc1WKqrPZ6OFv/FjiUAwrrEDGt6SwxkZM4oAbaNN3Hvn@7cRiPXTkcT38Aw "Factor – Try It Online")

Comment: @chunes Thanks! I have several more answers formatted this way, as a function. I didn't know then that a quotation is acceptible.

Answer (score 4):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 74 bytes

This ended up very similar to the Python answer. I was trying something noticeably more interesting with Aggregate, but the terrible no trailing whitespace requirement made it too long.

```cs
s=>s.SelectMany(c=>char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)?c+" "+c:"").Skip(2).SkipLast(2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY3LCsIwEEX3/YqQ1aSvheBG24ighUJFoa6FdBhqsEZJUrRfHytdnQuHy0GXodOhGg0Wzltt@pTVRzM@yapuoALvykrJKlay4Erp8pYGQn9SZgIs5V/ntWvIe7Jne9C99oBihwlnPMEN5yJvH/oNq4WNcn7eYRtFlznmwdCHLV2ogIOKuxhFsr5l3/l5fe2tVRMIIcIP)

Comment: This is really great - I love seeing C# answers. I originally thought of flattening the list with SelectMany, but decided not to. I ended up utilizing the c+" "+c pattern as well. I need to utilize SkipLast!

Comment: I'm  also realizing that char is way more powerful than I originally thought. There's no need to do the String -> char -> String

Answer (score 4):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), <s>77</s> 76 bytes

```
{it.filter{it.isLetterOrDigit()}.zipWithNext{a,b->"$a$b"}.joinToString(" ")}
```

Old solution

```
{it.replace("\\W|_".toRegex(),"").zipWithNext{a,b->"$a$b"}.joinToString(" ")}
```

Answer (score 4):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), <strike>52</strike> 54 bytes

```
{gsub("\\W|_",a);for(b=$0;c=substr(b,++d,2);)$d=c}--NF
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/Or24NElDKSYmvCZeSSdR0zotv0gjyVbFwDrZFihTXALk6Whrp@gYaVprqqTYJtfq6vq5/f/vqZ6rkJinkFqRmFuQk6oIAA)

*Fixed underscore rule goof (+2 chars), thanks to Pedro Maimere*

Here's what's going on with this one...

```
gsub("\\W",a)
```

Removes all the non-alphabetic characters from the input string since `$0` is the default target for `gsub`.  Using an unitialized variable `a` instead of `""` saves a byte.

Next the code loops through the string taking 2 character slices and assigns them to positional variables.

```
for(b=$0;
```

The setup has to save `$0` to another variable, since changing the positional variables impacts the collected input in `$0` as well.

```
c=substr(b,++d,2);
```

The "test" at the top of the loop does a couple of things in one statement:

- increments `d`, the "current character" pointer
- sets variable `c` to the next 2 character slices of the input
- the true/false test simple has the code looping until we run off the string and get a null

The body of the loop sets the next positional variable to the slice we just took.

```
$d=c
```

After all the positional variables have been set, there's one "garbage" entry on the end with one character.  So the test:

```
--NF
```

effectively drops that last positional variable and triggers the default action, which prints all the positional variables separated by a space.

Comment: Great explanation, again.

Comment: Nice piece of code! According to the question's examples, underscores (`_`) are meant to be erased. Unfortunately, gawk's `\W` is the same as `[^[:alnum:]_]`, so the underscores are not erased. Thus, the regex would become `"\\W|_"`.

Comment: Nice catch!  I'll update the code to add the underscore.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>23</s> <s>19</s> 18 bytes

```
žKÃ©g<F®Nè?®N>è?ð?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L6sQysONx9amW7jdmid3@EV9kDSDkgd3mD//7@9fWK8qo6hom2VsgMA)

This probably could be really shorter, but I just wasn't able to find the right tools for the job. -4 bytes thanks to petStorm and a further byte thanks to Command Master.

### Old Answer Explained

```
žj'_ммм©g<F®Nè?®N>è?' ?
žj                      # Push [a-zA-Z0-9_]
  '_м                   # Remove the "_" from the above string
     м                  # Remove all alphanum characters from the input, leaving non-alphanum chars
      м                 # Remove those non-alphanum chars from the input, leaving alphanum chars
       ©                # Put this string into the register
        g<F             # For N in range(0, len(input) - 1):
           ®Nè?         #   Index the string at position N and print
               ®N>è?    #   Index the string at position N + 1 and print
                    ' ? #   Print a space
```

Comment: [19 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L6sQysONx9amW7jdmid3@EV9kDSDkgd3mD//7@9fWK8qo6hom2VsgMA).

Comment: [18 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6D7vw82HVqbbuB1a53d4hT2QtANShzfY//9vb58Yr6pjqGhbpewAAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```
\W|_

M&!`..
¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wPya8Jp6Ly1dNMUFPj@vQNi6F//8dk7gck5JBOIXL1T7Dnsspp7SoqFKhLLM4Mz@PKzxVvShVQdlQkctTPVchMU8htSIxtyAnVZErJCOzWAGI4vPyS@IVclLTM5NyUrk0ErWStJI1tU3jdCu47O0T41V1DBVtq5QdAA) Link includes test cases. Explanation: Now basically a port of @Jarmex's Retina 1 solution, except that `M!` always joins with newlines, so I have explicitly change them to spaces. Previous 17-byte approach:

```
\W|_

\B.\B
$& $&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcPdCoIwFADg@/MUR/zNfsCLLmM5iOg@8EZamx5yMGdMC4vefRV8n6NJW@nj7Hj1dfURADXf1ByiBKPE@1JBqZr/Fg6sY8DNw7kXPvWoBwsVpY4wLAI4pT1KizTL/m4ogHOnR/wRdpgEGrppZQgymau8WSy3l/UMjEkRr4pg9w73Xw) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
\W|_
```

Delete any non-word character and any underscore (which is the only non-alphanumeric character that counts as a word character).

```
\B.\B
$& $&
```

Duplicate each inner character and space separate the results.

Comment: Another 17-byte solution, slightly different approach: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcNNC4IwGADg@/sr3iHmRyV46BjTIKJDt8CLNDd7ycGcMS0s@u@r4HkcTdpKH8aHxtfVRwCc2KLJMqgtoPelglK1/1fY847Dzjyce@FTj3qwUFHkCIOcwTHqUVqkWfZ3QwzOnR7xR9hhEmjoppUhiGWq0jZZbi7rGTiXIlzlbPsOii8 "Retina 0.8.2 – Try It Online")

Comment: @mathjunkie Actually I was just working on that approach myself, although I had it as 16 bytes because I used a pilcrow instead of `\n`.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 57 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.replace(/\W|_|(.)/g,(_,c)=>c?c+' '+c:'').slice(2,-2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZHRboIwFIbv9xRHzQIVhGDizRJkmnjhvYk3y0ipFVhKS1owaHx3dtyyxVVGmpOm/b@vp@WDnqhhuqybmVQH3h/j3sRLE2heC8q4G77tr@nVDUiY@27qMxIvWcI8BxyPvTgOCYwoMTb3Z3PSMyWNEjwQKneP7niVjQmBgS8MYZU9PaTZcPwrDRkbAA6DxA8A7GAzm6RI/mM2hZ1ei1brM5xKUyp5j2F6LUC00GrQOM5wPmEMSgMGqwIlbdeeO5rDJBrZx6Nrz4GjBWtkY1unAiqBd7SqBb@DEdtWUNHbrkSygw7nuFJDja1xW7QrsDkcqVRNivt5mQl@06FoV0Dx2zxWNOIVGmhuIuA55LiOLzrkdek0mzLiLd5n3Z@roZd@/4UFLDobSxKaPvvRKL5MXh@wCKJL/wk)

Comment: The approach looks promising so far.

Answer (score 3):

## Q/KDB+, 38 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{" "sv -2_2#'next\[x inter .Q.an _52]}
```

**Examples:**

```
q){" "sv -2_2#'next\[x inter .Q.an _52]}"Ab"
"Ab"
q){" "sv -2_2#'next\[x inter .Q.an _52]}"Abc"
"Ab bc"
q){" "sv -2_2#'next\[x inter .Q.an _52]}"E?h?"
"Eh"
q){" "sv -2_2#'next\[x inter .Q.an _52]}"This is _not_ legible"
"Th hi is si is sn no ot tl le eg gi ib bl le"
```

**Explanation:**

```
{" "sv -2_2#'next\[x inter .Q.an _52]} / solution
{                                    } / lambda taking implicit x
                           .Q.an       / "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_0123456789"
                                 _52   / drop element at index 52
                   x inter             / intersection of x and alphanumerics
             next\[                 ]  / scan along input
          2#'                          / take first 2 characters of each
       -2_                             / drop final two items
 " "sv                                 / join (sv) with " "
```

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 32 bytes ([SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS))

Port of Surculose Sputum's Python answer.

```apl
{¯2↓2↓⊃,/{⍵' '⍵}¨⍵∩⎕A,819⌶⎕A,⎕D}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24TqQ@uNHrVNBuFHXc06@tWPereqK6gDydpDK4Dko46Vj/qmOupYGFo@6tkGZgIJl1qgbgV1xcSkZEV7dS4gUyNRK0krWVPbNE63Qh0A)

Answer (score 3):

## [QuadR](https://github.com/abrudz/QuadRS), 18 bytes

```apl
1↓∊' ',¨2,/⍵
\W|_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyxNTCn6/9/wUdvkRx1d6grqOodWGOnoP@rdyhUTXhPP9f9/SEZmsQIQxefll8Qr5KSmZyblpAIA)

Replaces all non-word characters and underscores (`\W|_`) with nothing , and then:

`2,/⍵` adjacent pairs

`' ',¨` prepend a space to each pair

`∊` **ϵ**nlist (flatten)

`1↓` drop the first space

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 80 bytes

```c
p,b;f(char*s){for(p=b=0;*s;s++)isalnum(*s)?p&&printf(" %c%c"+!b--,p,*s),p=*s:0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HUzNaoQwGLznKT5ddBN/QA@9NIjdQg@9F3oorSRp1ECMIdF228Vnt7Ewwwwzw4hyEGLfbcFpj8XIXObJrZ8dtg1vKpp56vOcKM@0WSccytamqXXKLD2OIRGJiPOIl2Vhi1AWtsn8fUW3/bgC/1ZX1TtFYQ0TUwYTuCH4HpWWgAe5eJx68p9Bjz2hQe0a0jg@/IbAyWV1BiqKNtgvHF24OPiJntqxRY96de4HvpRXs0Gv8uwknOoIPZ8nYAbklU1Wywi9jMpDQGfmpQMtB8W1RJhlPBMkv/sor6htWZcUddT8nh7@AA)

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript ES6, <s>55</s> 54 chars

```
s=>s.replace(/\W|_/g,"").replace(/.(?=(.).)/g,"$&$1 ")
```

Test:

```js
f=s=>s.replace(/\W|_/g,"").replace(/.(?=(.).)/g,"$&$1 ")

console.log(`Ab -> Ab
Abc -> Ab bc
Abcd -> Ab bc cd
E?h? -> Eh
Blurry vision -> Bl lu ur rr ry yv vi is si io on
We're #1! -> We er re e1
I'm an example! -> Im ma an ne ex xa am mp pl le
This is _not_ legible -> Th hi is si is sn no ot tl le eg gi ib bl le
(a*b*c)+5^-x -> ab bc c5 5x
??a_%,1!=z#@ -> a1 1z`.split`
`.map(s=>s.split` -> `).map(([s,k])=>f(s)==k).every(x=>x))
```

Comment: @tsh, yep, nice. I removed `+`, but forgot about braces.

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 32 bytes

```
[:}:[:,/2,&' '\]-.-.&AlphaNum_j_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYlNa8JAGITv/orRYN7EJqsWvKykMZYWBOlBCj2kumziaiKbD2ItKvjbo1sKM/MwM4e2x2iHgIPgYQT@sM/wulq@tzG/8Zh7w2fPJtD32mc@syNdZ/LjVIiDaN0OOirNKjge37mw2QsoSmhqMv3H1vAtzELDuT41zQW/@TGvSjN8KaJGwRp3TVsQFZAl1FkWtVZ/22eWH/GQKKsfAa32eaKVORw5SAap@zTZ@GfTw1CK/rgbXK0ZtXc)

```
               -.-.&AlphaNum_j_   remove non-alphanumeric
       2,&' '\                    append space to each pair of adjacent chars 
     ,/                           join 
 }:                               remove trailing space
```

Comment: Nice answer, I think `[:}:@,2,&' '\]-.-.&AlphaNum_j_` works for -2.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 98 bytes

```r
function(x,y=grep("[a-z0-9]",el(strsplit(x,"")),T,,T))for(i in seq(y)[-1])cat(y[i-1:0],' ',sep='')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hc2xCsMgEADQX7Eu3sEJydiCez8g0EEc0tQU4VCrBmp/3pbOb3hl3PkoZuxH3FpIEd7UzbP4DNKu@jPps5PkGWorNXNoP5cSkRaiBXFPBYIIUVT/go5Wzw63tUG3Qc@XyZESiqrPRin8RyCvnjmRuKXCj5PE8QU)

Unusually for [R](https://www.r-project.org/), a `for` loop is significantly shorter than a [matrix-based approach](https://tio.run/##Hc1LCsIwEADQq2hWMzCBZimYvetQcFG6SJOpFoY25APWy1fpBd7LxyQt22Nua6jLtsKHnHUcW2B0kHypTD4l2eHNPkKYljXCftevzAnU4PW307dREQuUmkuSpf4JpRCpJ@qR9kGbEUkbJEOOZnuaHeIZg3qwyEaX55YlXhUePw), mainly because it allows us to just use `cat` instead of the much-more-verbose `Reduce(paste` vectorized way to build a text string from a list of characters.

Comment: [78 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/qflFNapGCj@z@tNC@5JDM/T6NYJ9g2vbg0SUMpOi5Rt8pA1zJWSUdJSadYJ0RTx8/W0EojLzkjsUgjWFPXUFMzObFEA6i4uKQoMy9dI1jHT8dPGygMNlZDySM1JydfRyE8vygnRVFJ8z8A)

Comment: @Giuseppe Much better than mine: please post it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 76 bytes

```r
function(s)cat(substring(S<-gsub("[^a-z0-9]","",s,T),N<-1:(nchar(S)-1),N+1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qflFNapGCj@z@tNC@5JDM/T6NYMzmxRKO4NKm4pCgzL10j2EY3HcjTUIqOS9StMtC1jFXSUVLSKdYJ0dTxs9E1tNLIS85ILNII1tQ1BIpoG2pqgg3VUPJIzcnJ11EIzy/KSVFU0vwPAA)

Similar to Dominic van Essen's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220084/67312), uses `cat` to join by spaces; uses `substring` which recycles (as opposed to `substr` which doesn't).

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 25 bytes

```perl
s/\W|_//g;s/\B.\B/$& $&/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YPya8Jl5fP90ayHLSi3HSV1FTUFHTT///3ymntKioUiEsszgzP@9ffkEJkCr@r1sAAA)

Comment: Nice! I'm surprised I didn't post this, given the sed answer! You can also save a byte using `s/\Pl//g` too!

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 26 bytes

```
≔ΦＳ№⁺α⁺β⭆χλιθ⪫Ｅ⊖Ｌθ✂θι⁺²ι¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzBCsIwEETv/Yq1HtxABOu1J6kIikKhB88xLm0gbtt06@/HRr3MHN6bsZ0Jtjc@xsM0uZbx5LxQwDMPszQSHLeoNFT9zIK1nyc0Gr790PDjNzNgsdPglVpMl2JUZVYvTPDSO8ZkHMkGehELPfFK3EqHY1Ib7yzhuAz/v/v0oaFIMIdcqTLGO20CwbpYZXH79h8) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔ΦＳ№⁺α⁺β⭆χλιθ
```

Filter out any character that can't be found in the upper or lower case alphabet and isn't a digit.

```
⪫Ｅ⊖Ｌθ✂θι⁺²ι¹
```

Extract all substrings of length 2 and join them together on spaces.

Answer (score 2):

## [C#], <s>163</s> <s>155</s> <s>133</s> <s>128</s> <s>127</s> <s>128</s> <s>114</s> <s>112</s> <s>133</s> 98 bytes

```
i=>{var b=i.Where(char.IsLetterOrDigit);return b.Select((n,i)=>i==0|i==b.Count()-1?n+"":n+" "+n);}
```

[Run it](https://tio.run/##XVHva9swEP1s/xVXd6NynZjmw77MdbKta6GQsbEW8qF0QVYutkCWE/3IkmX@27NTksEYiHvcuyfd052wQ2HFwVupa3jaWYdtEf@b5VOp1/9Rz7h1@XesveLmfrsyaK3stC3ieOUrJQUIxa2Fb6arDW/jfRydeeu4I9h0cgFfuNQsjSOqRhtuQOqVd1CCxp@kM9Tu5RX2kHyskkGI4gyLgPfNJMAn5Y3ZwUaG/oGY4ZVBuBxdhOTxqgWuAbe8XSk8Us@NtEBnrjs3B4W1rBSGAuPX1bVIs3c/htuQTyZ8/nYwuih/XX5IoKevnW0uzxYfvBa3J58DWOw0b6UYMzjIcrwPuqqU@axBg0w03OSPdorOoflqPstaurQw6LzRUOVPqFA4xvRApuVYluXNbwpVftd57Vg6HE10liTvKUCS6bToD1GUFsHOsjPAQi9Pnm4KgtvTFPMp6to1xGQZTfg4YoCgXJNyyY6iF/9Kz4TCHe2uU5jPjHRI60b2Jtn/1fQwHNMaTj8lU1pwx9Yp9Mnxdh/T6Q9/AA)

<s>Have not used a Regex yet in a Codegolf, so very excite.</s> Regex uses way too many characters. No longer excite.

- 127 bytes: removed a "." in the regex string
- 126 bytes: replaced String.Join("" with String.Concat
- 114 bytes: changed || to |, removed the ( ) { return; } from inside the Select
- 112 bytes: Removed + from regex
- 128 bytes: Reverting back to older solution. Entry now legal (thanks to @Neil and @my pronoun is monicareinstate)
- 98 bytes:  Realization that char is way more powerful than I thought (thanks to @my pronoun is monicareinstate's C# solution), removed the string -> char -> string conversions

Comment: Under standard rules this is a snippet rather than a function so you should include the `(i,j,p)=>{}` to make it legal, but you can at least copy the `"\\W|_"` that everyone else is using (with two backslashes because it's inside a string literal). Also I think `i==0` can be `i<1` to save another byte.

Comment: Actually you don't use `j` or `p`, so they can go too, so with the other changes you're still ahead overall.

Comment: Besides, for some weird reason you have to count `using` directives. While the awesome interactive compiler imports several, you still have to count `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;` :(

Comment: Ah Neil, thanks, I will change it.

Comment: @ my pronoun is monicareinstate  do  you have a link for more info on that rule? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

## [Icon](https://github.com/gtownsend/icon), 92 bytes

```
procedure f(s)
t:=""
find(k:=!s,&letters++&digits--'_')&t||:=k||' '||k&\z
return t[3:-2]
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU9Na4NAEL37K0ZD3d2oh7T0IohNoIfeCz2kifgxJou6ht2xTcP@99SVHjoM83hv4PGerEd1v1/0WGMzaYSWG@FRmgWB10rV8C7NfBOHPRKhNlEUNvIkySQJK5gIydo066xlwKztws@bp5EmrYD2T2nyePBQNf/Mh1IqLjyYh9CQgTSDfbCtghjmW/9B4/A1P@cOd/2k9Q98SSNH5YQPZLPTauM78sYGKBXgtRwuPS7S@1kamLdQIxXQ40lWPboHL9fVuhbR8zG5Op7nZfEQb/zstnqZ@WGJ9a0lIW@5v@QTwlVyHX4B)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <strike>86</strike> 74 bytes

<sup>-12 bytes thanks to Khuldraeseth na'Barya</sup>

```hs
import Data.Char
unwords.map(\(x,y)->[x,y]).(zip<*>tail).filter isAlphaNum
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dcq7CgIxEEDR3q@YMhHNF7gLorXVdirLqIkZnDxIZvHx8zHVhcP1WF@WuTUKORWBIwqag8eycsMS36k8qgmY1UV9Nl@9Hc89V23Uj/JuPQoSa@OIxRaguufs8bSEFpAiDECxO94FXJs81X7AHJPMwPZJN7Z/)

Comment: `\x->zip x$tail x` is `zip<*>tail` for four bytes of savings.

Comment: `uncurry$(.pure).(:)` is `\(a,b)->[a,b]` for another six.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0 [`-S`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
r\W ä+
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&flags=LVM&code=clxXIOQr&input=IkJsdXJyeV92aXNpb24i)

```
r\W ä+     :Implicit input of string
r          :Replace
 \W        :  Regex /[^a-z0-9]/gi
    ä+     :Consecutive pairs reduced by concatenation
           :Implicit output, joined with spaces
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 159 bytes (-2 more bytes thanks to S.S. Anne and JustinCB)

```c
main(a,b)char**b;{b++;for(a=0;a<strlen(*b);a++){if(isalnum((*b)[a])){a?putchar((*b)[a]):0;a&&a<strlen(*b)-1?putchar(32):0;a<strlen(*b)-1?putchar((*b)[a]):0;}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYzLCsIwEEV/xVWZSSz42BnFDxEXk2A1kKYyaQQJ@fbRuihduD3nnuvau3MiPfkItLboHsRKWVOs1qYbGOi0MXRMI4dbBGXRkNZYfAc@UYi5hwle6IpY6PzM43Qws8O3bZpl3m7n0X738//l4qHWKiI2ZOb36uWTH@IH)

Comment: You can save some bytes: `i;main(a,b)char**b;{b++;for(i=0;i<strlen(*b);i++){if(isalnum((*b)[i]))putchar(i?(*b)[i]:0);putchar(i&&i<strlen(*b)-1?32:0);putchar(i<strlen(*b)-1?(*b)[i]:0);}}`

Comment: The above version moves the declaration of `i` outside of main, allowing it to be implicitly declared as an `int`(saving 4 bytes) & moves the declaration of `b`'s type after the function declaration, K&R-style, which allows `a` to be implicitly declared as an `int`(saving 2 bytes)

Comment: Actually, for your code to work properly for the more advanced test cases, you need to wrap the `putchar`'s in brackets, adding 2 bytes: `i;main(a,b)char**b;{b++;for(i=0;i<strlen(*b);i++){if(isalnum((*b)[i])){putchar(i?(*b)[i]:0);putchar(i&&i<strlen(*b)-1?32:0);putchar(i<strlen(*b)-1?(*b)[i]:0);}}}`

Comment: Cool, thanks! I'll update the answer.

Comment: I don't think outputting null bytes is allowed. Also, you can remove `i;` and use `a` instead.

Comment: @S.S.Anne cool, i'll update the answer!

Comment: I think this fails for cases like ’??a_%,1!=z#@’.

Comment: You can fix outputting null bytes by moving the ternary operator outside of the `putchar`(this also includes @S.S.Anne 's byte reduction): `main(a,b)char**b;{b++;for(a=0;a<strlen(*b);a++){if(isalnum((*b)[a])){a?putchar((*b)[a]):0;a&&a<strlen(*b)-1?putchar(32):0;a<strlen(*b)-1?putchar((*b)[a]):0;}}}`

Comment: @JustinCB thanks, I'll update the post.

Comment: [128 bytes](https://tio.run/##NclBDsIgEADAr1SSNiwLxnqUVh9iPCzEKsmWGmhNjPp21IOXuYw3F@9LYTtSiJK0A3@lpJSzT@7znPgcpUJ0YIcpSeo3ljq2hAghE8dllHRU7gRNc0shzoMU9brNdf4pNB0IldsJoeWKXrRnswUU1Tc6Nu0/wb5LKY6XlB7VPeQwxQ8 "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 130 bytes

```
func[s][a: charset[#"0"-#"9"#"A"-#"Z"#"a"-#"z"]parse s[any[p: change
a(rejoin[p/1" "p/1])| remove skip]]take/part/last s 2 at s 3]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5vS8NADMbf91NkKbI/UuYUXzjQOsEXvhVB2HGWtE3Xc@31uOvGNvzu9To7DCH55XkSiOW8e@dcyKBYQlfsdCacFLSErCTruBUh3mAU4gOGuOph7YF6OKE0/Qo4QfoozPlEbzigieXvRmlh5gsE9FVOf8By3ez98lYZKVva8txft/OKXAsOboH6die7orFMWQkte0ME4ANXKV4g@6d8wNe4jAd8qXbWHmGvnGr0oH3y2DKEi9Ewv41rIA18oNpUfFE/SuXAZ6KbNoGKNyqtePAmNEtn2fT6/is6DFIcU3K1GD2ewmcMpABjlfbvZo05/n2O0RNCcWYpu18)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 42 bytes

```
1}.[:,/2' '&,\]#~'/9@Z`z'(2|I."#.)&(3&u:)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYnbasJAGITvfYrRYP5sjGujeOGKJlYUhF6VQsFTmsS1ieRQoika2r566pbCzHzMzKlucTpiIkCw8ABxd5dj/vy0rO1vvhFWr08g3drutB/qjdz1W0VG/2vFWxpnujHQS8F2NWugIcMoh2GJI4POp6BZQGOV4T8OigsnchQfk7IobviMz3GeqeFVEhUSmt1UbUWUws8gr376kci/7SWKz7jLy/KLh0S@x0Ei1WH4ZmCGrDPcd6@qO47vte3mpNJcqn8B)

Inspired by [ngn's ngn/k solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203899/75681)

### Explanation

```
                                   (3&u:)     convert to integer both
                                         ]    the input
                 '/9@Z`z'                     and the symbols surrounding the digits, 
                                              uppercas and lowercase letters
                         (2|I."#.)&           and find in which interval lies each char
                                              then check if it's an odd one
              ]#~                             use the above to filter the input
       2' '&,\                                prepend each pair of adjacent chars
                                              with a space
   [:,/                                       flatten the result 
1}.                                           and drop the leading space
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>54</s> 76 bytes

```javascript
a=>[...a.replace(/[\W_-]/g,'')].map((a,b,c)=>a+c[b+1]).slice(0,-1).join(' ')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcpBDoMgEADArxgv7EZY6wPwGz1Q0qwUDQaBiG36e9o5z84fru4M5VIpv3xbdWM9GyJiOn2J7DyM5nF/KjtuUgi0dHABYLlIh3rmwZllmCxSjeF/b1JNSHsOCUQnsLmcao6eYt5ghd5/@SjRdyGV99Ujth8)

Comment: Hello and welcome to CGCC! Looks like this code isn't ignoring special characters as the spec requires (eg. `??a_%,1!=z#@` should become `a1 1z`). Hopefully it's an easy fix :)

Comment: @mathjunkie Sorry, completely missed the comment saying that non-alphanumeric characters must be removed, it's fixed but it makes my answer a lot less competitive.

Comment: You can save 2 bytes with `.join\` \``

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>123</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>117</s></sup> 116 bytes

```c
i;f(char*s){char*t=s;for(i=0;t[i+=!!isalnum(*s++)]=*s;);for(putchar(*t++);t[1];)printf("%c %1$c",*t++);putchar(*t);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dcxNa8MgGMDxez6FSReqeYHaJCfJuh13H@zQdUWdaYXElJiObqWfPat1uB0cCA88/n8Pz3ecT5MkDeR7OiQanW9zrDVp@gHKekHGtUzrMJSaturYwUSnKdrUiSbolhyOoyEwGa/7a4w3BB0GqcYGRjEHMb7jUWY/f1NELlNHpYLoHJgV0Iv1po4eWUQChzXI70GU6QUiQQNvw7bUtvxP/KpcTm1OXc5@8nd/z2zPXG9y1h6H4RN8SC175XeWOYUNexHzQYAZDv0EW4MdWhr0NO8AVUCcaHdoxT90aenS0cLQ573U4Pq2qh@3oBU7yVrhP1DYA4U7UJoDkCYs4Sit3vKT35XWlc5Vxq1WdBtnOKy/Zg9@V1lnxmX6Bg)

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
£Q·H°·
```

[Run and debug it at staxlang.xyz!](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=9c51fa48f8fa&i=Ab%0AAbc%0AAbcd%0AE%3Fh%3F%0ABlurry+vision%0AWe%27re+%231%21%0AI%27m+an+example%21%0AThis+is+_not_+legible%0A%28a*b*c%29%2B5%5E-x%0A%3F%3Fa_%25,1%21%3Dz%23%40&a=1&m=2)

#### Unpacked (7 bytes) and explanation:

```
VL|&2BJ
VL         Push string of all alphanumeric characters.
  |&       Remove from the input all letters not in this string.
    2B     All length-2 substrings
      J    Join with spaces
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/), 120 bytes

```js
b=fn w->import String;l=replace(w,~r/[\W_]/,"");for(i<-0..String.length(l)-2,do: at(l,i)<>at(l,i+1))|>Enum.join(" ") end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBPa8JAEMXvfooxUtzVJDYFL1WTKnjw1EMFD/0TNsmabNlswibRKKVf3Y5ILE2FYRjmvfnxGC5FLfSpcwpmWwV7yxVpnukSXkotVDyRM81zyUJO9ua3Hr2@bfz3kWkYdLLNNBFT6962L1ZbchWXCZHUejCj7BFYSaQp6NS9DEOH0i93qarU/syEIgYYFLiKTqtnW6gi52FJApsY88CgFHqWC/Og808Lf0UIwht69McAYdT2LL3EazzLpK0uZKX1AXaiEJlqbAsJsoJKg8Y6wGGHOogCCuwZZKoN2fC@5tBzug1gw4HjKXan7V31U2AKeM3SXPLrxSqFlJ0FhUc11DjjJocco/A2Y51gGCxfZaWPeiwCyRvSOoHkmhY7IjFzCeWZBDyGGPf4q1tgwgbBIKTD8YdVNzx2@esYxnXb7nnMvzOd7uzYe7raHXCOpx8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 31 bytes

```perl6
{@$_ Z~.skip}o{S:g/\W|_//.comb}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU9da8JAEHy/XzFi26it2jzYh4JGBR98riD0K9zFMwm95MJdlESrfz3uKQjLsDuzs8MW0qi3JqvxtMUYzXH6EOLzPLB/aXHSx4/3ePi9/g@Hw0GkM3FqLK9x3mJgC5WWHa8/8bpfrz/YagOV5tI2M4H@BDPBZiK6dRCRGzb3CdGGLYIkcMQiYXO1M6bGPrWpzh03V1A77AwMVY16TxpSC0uooXO2lp6RaPstt72WkLRH6LOll4HnkBXPCiWv8jJDxh2Z00aFinpiChQUItkqobtUYa7LkIg4FUo62ypBcg8lJD9FlyidDTJGTDw9c73S4T3Ri7rPo99@5cz89uUIo4oFAQ8fX/zW@NCeXjUf/uEC)

The extra requirement for stripping non-alphanumeric characters takes up more than half of the bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## F#, 130 bytes

```
let f s=s|>Seq.filter Char.IsLetterOrDigit|>fun x->Seq.tail x|>Seq.zip x|>Seq.map(fun(a,b)->string a+string b)|>String.concat" "
```

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 47 bytes

```
{" "/2':x^"!@#$%^&*()~`_-+={}[]|\:;\"'<>?,./ "}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6pWUlDSN1K3qohTUnRQVlGNU9PS0KxLiNfVtq2ujY6tibGyjlFSt7Gz19HTV1Cq5eJKi1ZyyiktKqpUKMsszszPU4oFCbnaZ9hDWI5JySkQlr19YryqjqGibZWyA0QkJCOzWAGI4vPyS+IVclLTM5NyUiFS4anqRakKyoaKEK5GolaSVrKmtmmcbgVExFM9VyExTyG1IjG3ICcVqAwAGFs02g==)

The window adverb finally got a use for once. Also, removing non-alphanumeric is such a huge pain to write.

Anyways, here's the explanation:

```
{" "/2':x^"!@#$%^&*()~`_-+={}[]|\:;\"'<>?,./ "}  Main function. Takes x as input
          "!@#$%^&*()~`_-+={}[]|\:;\"'<>?,./ "   Hard-coded non-alphanumeric string
        x^                                       Remove all of them in x
     2':                                         Window (Get chunks of x at length 2)
 " "/                                            Join the chunks with whitespace
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 57 bytes

```lua
io.write((...):gsub('%W',''):gsub('.','%1 %1'):sub(3,-3))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P8/M1@vvCizJFVDQ09PT9Mqvbg0SUNdNVxdR10dxtMDclQNFVQNgSIgAWMdXWNNzf///zvllBYVVSqUZRZn5ucpAAA)

Performs three steps:

- Removes all non-alphanumerics

  `Blurry vision` -> `Blurryvision`
- Double all characters, with a space in between

  `Blurryvision` -> `B Bl lu ur rr ry yv vi is si io on n`
- Remove the excess characters

  `B Bl lu ur rr ry yv vi is si io on n` -> `Bl lu ur rr ry yv vi is si io on`

Answer (score 1):

## [Erlang (escript)](http://erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html), 110 bytes

Port of the Python answer.

```erlang
f(X)->R=lists:flatten([[I]++" "++[I]||I<-X,re:run([I],"[A-Za-z0-9]")/=nomatch]),string:slice(R,2,length(R)-4).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYzLCsIwFAX3fkWNCLlNri90YbE@lt12JZYosaQ1EKMkEUX895ql4FkNzHCUM9K2qHzt9D10va6he8B1mRvtg88aI0NQllZVIRgjCWEs0udTrHDPncrcI7pCcFLt8CDxPcGlIDDO7e0qQ30RwH1w2raZN7pWtOQzbpRtw4WWgHMYdVep44OABNe9JE7fsubpdFC0oYTK9JzWwBZHfBEAHqU1FPh/udnI05BP@/l7sP0pR90X)

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 59 bytes

```java
s->s.replaceAll("\\W|_","").replaceAll(".(?=(.).)","$0$1 ")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU/BTgIxEL3zFUNhQ4tL4x68gLBiookHT5hwEN10ly4Uu92m7W5A5dtrAS8k8zJ582bey@xYy0a79ZcXla6Ng13gtHFC0rJRhRO1osNJp5DMWnhlQsFPB0A3uRQFWMdcaG0t1lAFDS@cEWrz/gHMbCw5rwI8//vcX9T40mZQTr0dzSw1XEtW8LmUGK1Wy98MxQiRqzHF6RRTQkmQ@rf9BBDxk7N5WRvALTPguHXjq1yAxcE6XtG6cVSHTFdiFNkxRDZSKD5fxFBSprU84BMj5GJ67Jxw9H6ehypOWPundJv6R9kYc4BW2PCQX/KB4dBLuv5lUAFTwPes0pJ3/dtWWAiVqdplIPlG5JJ7zIb5sCA3d5@jvU9TlkVx0p1@9x7@AA)

Answer (score 1):

## Swift, 141 bytes

```
{let a=$0.unicodeScalars.filter{CharacterSet.alphanumerics.contains($0)};return zip(a,a.dropFirst()).map{"\($0)\($1)"}.joined(separator:" ")}
```

Ungolfed:

```
let ungolfed: (String) -> String = { input in
    let unicodeScalars = input.unicodeScalars.filter { char in CharacterSet.alphanumerics.contains(char) }
    return zip(unicodeScalars, unicodeScalars.dropFirst())
        .map { "\($0)\($1)" }
        .joined(separator: " ")
}
```

Test case runner:

````
import Foundation

let testCases: [(input: String, expectedOutput: String)] = [
    (input: "Ab", expectedOutput: "Ab"),
    (input: "Abc", expectedOutput: "Ab bc"),
    (input: "Abcd", expectedOutput: "Ab bc cd"),
    (input: "E?h?", expectedOutput: "Eh"),
    (input: "Blurry vision", expectedOutput: "Bl lu ur rr ry yv vi is si io on"),
    (input: "We're #1!", expectedOutput: "We er re e1"),
    (input: "I'm an example!", expectedOutput: "Im ma an ne ex xa am mp pl le"),
    (input: "This is _not_ legible", expectedOutput: "Th hi is si is sn no ot tl le eg gi ib bl le"),
    (input: "(a*b*c)+5^-x", expectedOutput: "ab bc c5 5x"),
    (input: "??a_%,1!=z#@", expectedOutput: "a1 1z"),
]

for (input, expectedOutput) in testCases {
    let actualOutput = f(input)
    assert(actualOutput == expectedOutput, """
    Wrong answer.
        input: '\(input)'
        actualOutput: '\(actualOutput)'
        expectedOutput: '\(expectedOutput)'

    """)
}
```
````

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 82 chars

```
a=[c for c in input() if c.isalnum()]
print(' '.join(a+b for a,b in zip(a,a[1:])))
```

Try it: https://ideone.com/dxJU8e

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), <s>48</s> 47 bytes

```powershell
''+($args-match'[a-z\d]'|%{,"$p$_"*!!$p;$p=$_})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RVJLT8JAEL73V3zgYgHbQw@cCAE1mnjSCIkHH81SxramL3e3WkB@O05ZwWYzmfkes9PdrcpvUjqhLPOjUtFevGOC7d51L/pCqlj7uTRR4j5Lf/OyenV/eluvKyoRdoedjqjGopqIcDfY7xxn1nccr@9eLl0PbRzYKrIlODkiqxMEzg/ozTSZtuhNYuurrFZqja9Up2XRElcZshq1guK1xvqLOaQammMJ1rS27hO5inAWdLpseSIQizkGlr1zc8gC1Mi8yuigucuRyxYsWNag4ZyRChVvR3aURcLb8AqL0oSMxumSKfYuEiSnGThyE57EwLReUIyYcf7L/1Z9OVwOo8HF6M1v2g7SnsEIo8YKplMZ9rygM9mczQ6CAMGGKWeAH/SwdcCf0EalRexBUFNRZGjFVyZCyynSdWYYOOebnFnlgXl@mF/X2pT5/fKDTa@zLeZ1FJHWrfvP5kf0@d92jMdjt6Ng5@x4kttS8bPwF5JPAv5lbcp5uqH9Lw)

Answer (score 1):

## APL ([NARS2000](https://www.nars2000.org/) dialect) 24 bytes

```
{¯1↓1↓⍕2,/⍵/⍨⍵∊A←⎕a,⎕A,⎕D}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
kr↔zṄ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwia3LihpR64bmEIiwiIiwiQWJcbkFiY1xuQWJjZFxuRT9oP1xuQmx1cnJ5IHZpc2lvblxuV2UncmUgIzEhXG5JJ20gYW4gZXhhbXBsZSFcblRoaXMgaXMgX25vdF8gbGVnaWJsZVxuKGEqYipjKSs1Xi14XG4/P2FfJSwxIT16I0AiXQ==)

```
kr↔   # Remove non-alphanumeric
   z  # Get chunks of length 2
    Ṅ # Join with spaces
```

Comment: 20 bytes: [Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=S&code=kr%E2%86%94%3A%C2%A32%E1%BA%87'%E2%82%83%C2%AC%3B%C2%A5%E1%B8%A22%E1%BA%87'%E2%82%83%C2%AC%3BY&inputs=abcdef&header=&footer=)

Comment: @astonearachnid Thanks! Building on that, I got to 15 bytes.

Comment: [Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=S&code=kLkd%2B%E2%86%942lv%E1%B9%85&inputs=Blurry%20vision&header=&footer=) for 10

Comment: [Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=S&code=kr%E2%86%942lv%E1%B9%85&inputs=Blurry%20vision&header=&footer=) for 7

Comment: now [5 bytes](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwia3LihpR64bmEIiwiIiwiQWJcbkFiY1xuQWJjZFxuRT9oP1xuQmx1cnJ5IHZpc2lvblxuV2UncmUgIzEhXG5JJ20gYW4gZXhhbXBsZSFcblRoaXMgaXMgX25vdF8gbGVnaWJsZVxuKGEqYipjKSs1Xi14XG4/P2FfJSwxIT16I0AiXQ==)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-pl`, <s>48</s> <s>39</s> 35 bytes

Similar to my own original solution, this is now basically a port of [Xcali's Perl 5 solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271599/11261); give them an upvote.

```ruby
gsub /\W|_/,""
gsub /\B.\B/,'\& \&'
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcnm0km5BjlLsgqWlJWm6FjeV04tLkxT0Y8Jr4vV1lJS4oFwnvRgnfR31GDWFGDV1iFKojgXrPdVzFRLzFFIrEnMLclIVIcIA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), <s>144 129 127 126 123 120</s> 106 bytes

-3 bytes, thanks @mousetail
-14 bytes, thanks @corvus_192

Playing with strings can be subtle, and as such it is easy to slam face first into the borrow checker when trying to golf string manipulation in rust. As a result I welcome any improvement to this code:

```rust
|s|{let a:String=s.filter(|c|c.is_alphanumeric()).flat_map(|c|[c,' ',c]).collect();a[2..a.len()-2].into()}
```

The solution is the same as for the Python one above.

Ungolfed:

```rust
// This first line is not part of the code snippet,
// but needs to be present in the driving code in order for type inference to work.
let blur: fn(std::vec::IntoIter<char>) -> String = 
    |s| {                                    // Take in an iterator over
                                             // a vector of chars and
        let a: String = s                    // build a new string
            .filter(|c| c.is_alphanumeric()) // by taking all alphanumeric characters
            .flat_map(|c| [c, ' ', c])       // and replacing them with a copy
                                             // of themselves around a space
            .collect();                      // and collecting them into a String.
        a[2..a.len() - 2].into()             // Then make a string slice of every 
                                             // character except the first and last
                                             // two and convert that slice
                                             // into a String.
                                             // `.into()` works because of the
                                             // function signature that is specified
                                             // on the first line.
};

println!(
    "{}",
    // We call this closure by passing it an iterator over a vector of characters
    // that we build by iterating over the characters in a string.
    blur("This is a string"    
        .chars()
        .collect::<Vec<_>>()
        .into_iter())
);
```

[Attempt this online](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZVJNj9owEJV65FcMrCpsmkRiJaQqfLUr7YFzq-6BpZHxOsSV46S2g2CBY39FLxzaH7X7a3YMbKpsLWs8mnnP8-K8339MZd3xaZhqyJnUhMKupYSDZQypJtY9xPFa8DieaVfMnDAjnjEzoRBO4IszUq9g_Ldyafjx6cfe7neeyuJzZ2yjVCrkkD3f80jahKkyY7rKhZGcUBqlirkkZ6UHzHnQhW7AFzTihVKCO0KHbH4dRSxSAoWF14tIogpCD-eJz-9-DVtpYWDuhHUJZ1YEwAtjkLsAqWHegsuadz4vOwH4uAgaVX4uAyZvOw91CzBvdG-n2dR3b7Nm_UZVxmxhLa0stAfcKFAVVAYM7i1s19gDacFiLAAxDfqd6BoBV_22p94JEEjC2G-iZt0cmAaxYXmpxAk7y_Hv-aJG-AY2mGOlhBLHiwa7zvzqfM1QC-5EFy5B6EouER-8BUFWi8aIU1C6A-cvB7GCFdbxmU6z_nEbmgnrLXucfhh8DzdeMDs_6wAGm-bHTacseR_02-PHq08nYB_6j6-QBZrzFcqsFcYl4mebLEltgMjb05LaQ3E8-ib4KJlMsObdk0hvSEoD6F2sQof1nSXa1indJp3dAe5dGE7uHewOqON_h11oh9bFjcfj-XwB)

Comment: Or -3 more bytes if you use `.flat_map(|c|[c,' ',c])` instead

Comment: Consider using ATO instead of TIO which has more up to date versions of many major languages

Comment: 103 bytes: `|s|{let a:String=s.filter(|c|c.is_alphanumeric()).flat_map(|c|[c,' ',c]).collect();a[2..a.len()-2].into()}`, usable as a `fn(&mut std::vec::IntoIter<char>) -> String`

Comment: Thanks @corvus_192! When you say 103 bytes, how are you counting them? I get it to 106.

Comment: You're right it's 106. I think I had some version with 103 bytes, but I can't remember .

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 70 bytes / 69 bytes

```
while(~$c=($s=preg_replace('/\W/','',$argn))[++$i])echo$s[$i-1],"$c ";
```

run these 70 bytes as pipe with `-nr`, ignore the warnings

or run this port of [Qwertiy´s JavaScript solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/204036/55735) (69 bytes) as pipe with `-nR`:

```
<?=preg_replace('/.(?=(.).)/','$0$1 ',preg_replace('/\W/','',$argn));
```

[Try them online](https://onlinephp.io/c/ac1f3)

Answer (score 1):

## Zsh, 65 bytes

```zsh
b=(${(s::)@//[^0-9A-Za-z]});for i ({2..$#b})printf $b[i-1]$b[i]\
```

[try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY1RT4MwFIXf9ys6Nh1MoYBspjOETWOiMfpgNEs2N0JZWZswim3nJoTfjg7io8lJvnO/@3AKSetEN8oa@3q/1OVkYkwhXK5tE83MRWQWq8q4SbgADOila1n9Hq6MXLBMJaCPl8x0ViesPkBNYso7VScB2gxrLeI/bppyH9CgKbfpXohv8MUk41lj5mQgCOg53eZ6HOxAlAFyjHZ5Slr3RpkEvwkzrkKQki3DKdHA6aVHQzyMjYvR2jy2Jgii8OzS6fpFb/rPIlUqlxMI1YEpRYQV8x0UHKd8y@IQShWpvYSOh5Dn2NcjezxG6Mob224gfdc@V34yLzYvuSue70YP73RRfL4u0NNBq38A)

There is a a space character after the backslash: `\`

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```
_.BMP(aXA,XD)J:s
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgwYKlpSVpuhYb4vWcfAM0EiMcdSJcNL2siiHCUNmbytFK4anqRakKyoaKCiEZmcUKQBSfl18Sr5CTmp6ZlJOqFAtVCwA)

#### Explanation

```lisp
_.BMP(aXA,XD)J:s
       XA         ; Regex matching any letter character
          XD      ; Regex matching any digit
         ,        ; Combine them using alternation (match one OR the other)
     (a     )     ; Find all matches in command-line argument
   MP             ; Map this function to each pair of adjacent results:
_                 ;  The first
 .                ;  concatenated with
  B               ;  the second
             J:s  ; Join the resulting list on spaces
```

Using the `-s` flag would remove the need for the final three bytes.

Comment: It looks like calling a function BMP on an object _ lol

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 75 bytes

```scala
_.map(c=>if(c.isLetterOrDigit)c+" "+c else"").mkString.drop(2).dropRight(2)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XY3BSgMxEIbvfYphTknX3YMiyMIWFG8qguKpVEnTZB3NZpdJWlukz-HBSz3oK_gsfRtDc_MyH_98wz-fP0Erp05-p1ia9eAUeTwCLH3_ptjjbP_Rz1-MjnCTDLyPABbGQpeCUNyGGs6Z1WZ6H5l8O5M1PHiK0BwuAYa0jc4LK_DCLZk3sKJAvUcp_3uhxvOxlsXpY7nOejtKY6Uc2BpEftBMMiU038toy7P91VPVqUHoZkJW6IrCtYnR8C1fUktR6gIBCw3GBYMoq-41F1QL7gdxLA-8o_Y5ppArv7aZu13mHw)

Answer (score 1):

## Uiua, 22 bytes

```
/$"_ _"◫2▽+⌵⊃±∊,+@0⇡10
```

[Try it](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__RiDihpAgLyQiXyBfIuKXqzLilr0r4oy14oqDwrHiiIosK0Aw4oehMTAKCkYgIkFiIgpGICJBYmMiCkYgIkFiY2QiCkYgIkVoPyIKRiAiQmx1cnJ5IHZpc2lvbiIKRiAiSSdtIGFuIGV4YW1wbGUhIgo=)

-1 + fix thanks to chunes :)

Explanation:

```
+@0⇡10
```

Take each number 0 to 9 and convert to character by adding it to character literal `0`

```
⊃±∊,
```

Apply [`sign ±`](https://www.uiua.org/docs/sign) to each character of the input, and [`member ∊`](https://www.uiua.org/docs/member) to the digit list and each character of the input. The former gives 0 for non-letters, 1 for uppercase letters, and -1 for lowercase letters. The latter gives 1 if the character is a digit and 0 otherwise.

```
+⌵
```

Take the absolute value of each result from `sign ±`, yielding a list of 1 and 0. Then, add this list to the results of `member ∊`. This results in a list with 1 at every position where there's a letter or a digit, and 0 everywhere else.

```
▽
```

[`keep ▽`](https://www.uiua.org/docs/keep) takes two lists and, in the case of the top containing only 0's and 1's, acts as a filter, removing any items from the first list that correspond with a 0 in the second. Here, the first list is the input string, and the second list is the filter created above.

So far, everything has just been the task of removing non-alphanumeric characters. The main task itself is much shorter:

```
◫2
```

The size-2 [`windows ◫`](https://uiua.org/docs/windows) of the list. This gives the overlapping pairs of the string.

```
/$"_ _"
```

[`reduce /`](https://www.uiua.org/docs/reduce) passes the first two items through a function, then that result and the next item through the same function, repeatedly until there are no more items left. `$"_ _"` is a format string, which becomes a function where each `_` becomes replaced with an item from the stack. This operation results in the list joined by spaces.

Comment: You also need to get rid of underscores, which inconveniently are matched by the `\w` regex.

Comment: [-1](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__ZiDihpAgLyQiXyBfIuKXqzLilr0r4oy14oqDwrHiiIosK0Aw4oehMTAKCmYgIkFiIgpmICJBYmMiCmYgIkFiY2QiCmYgIkU_aD8iCmYgIkJsdXJyeSB2aXNpb24iCmYgIldlJ3JlICMxISIKZiAiSSdtIGFuIGV4YW1wbGUhIgpmICJUaGlzIGlzIF9ub3RfIGxlZ2libGUiCmYgIihhKmIqYykrNV4teCIKZiAiPz9hXyUsMSE9eiNAIgo=) without the underscore problem.

Comment: @chunes thanks! That’s close to what my original idea was but a bit shorter

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 56 bytes

```powershell
$n=$args|% t*y|%{$_+" "+$_}
-join$n[0..($n.length-2)+-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/f9fJc9WJbEovbhGVaFEq7JGtVolXltJQUlbJb6WSzcrPzNPJS/aQE9PQyVPLyc1L70kQ9dIU1vXMPb////qSTmlRUWVCiWpFSXqAA)

-20 bytes for @mazzy

Comment: nice. you don't need `$s`. see [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/f9fJc9WJbEovbhGVaFEq7JGtVolXltJQUlbJb6WSzcrPzNPJS/aQE9PQyVPLyc1L70kQ9dIU1vXMPb////qSTmlRUWVCiWpFSXqAA "PowerShell Core – Try It Online")

Comment: @mazzy thanks for it!

Comment: Wasif, I think improvements are needed here. See test case `Blurry vision`

Answer (score 0):

## [Java 8 (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 144 bytes

No regexp, using only a single inline Stream

```java
s->s.chars().filter(e->e>47&e<58|e>64&e<91|e>96&e<123).mapToObj(e->""+(char)e).reduce("",(a,b)->a+(a.length()<2?b:" "+a.charAt(a.length()-1)+b))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZLLTsMwEEX3fMUQBNikiRTez4QisUACsQDEAkE1caeti@NEtlu1PL69OFWR2CBbXlzNHI/vlWaMU0zqhvS4/75oJqWSAoRCa@EOpYbPtTUAqR2ZAQqCW18Afx6ckXoIA7YSlp/5@ncLW4fOz7gFBRcLm@Q2FSM0lvF0IJWfwyjJKd8/2qLzg@Mvyg/3vTrJvDo59Crb3eNphc1jfV@OWzaKYtZO4MRTQ/2JIBZFHYadkic5xgxTRXroRoyf7xblaQRRjMsvu@5PL8l4XHK@OGstrmKunE5r2YfKh12FeXkFNEPLl1Ef5tZRldYTlza@6ZRmKh2wqFtGfJn5f0CEiX4AuS5GRQC5UhNj5jCVVtY6wD7TtiHYyNYD3M12BaiBZlg1ikL040ha8Lena9cDRUNZKgq8YbhT7ggeH7wlswBaFNjb7GTrFx8blwH0SWsSZC0aqeYg6tb9DPwuqHYNfj35Lf1e/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 9 bytes (18 nibbles)

```
*" "`'`:<<;|@\$n>>$
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWN1W1FJQUlLgUEtQVEqy4FBRsbBSsgZRCjYKDQoxKHpBpZ6egAlEM1bNgf3iqelGqgrKhokJIRmaxAhDF5-WXxCvkpKZnAk2HKAMA)

#### Explanation

```
*" "`'`:<<;|@\$n>>$
            @        Line of stdin
           |         Filter its characters on this function:
             \$n      Character is alphanumeric
          ;          Store the result as $
        <<           Remove last character
                >>$  Take another copy of $ and remove first character
      `:             Put both strings in a list
    `'               Transpose, giving a list of 2-character strings
*" "                 Join on spaces
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `Ṡ`, 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
œȦDḣZ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faHm00sOdC5RiFywtLUnTtVh5dPKJZS4PdyyOWlKclFwMFV2wNSQjs1gBiOLz8kviFXJS0zOTclIhkgA)

##### Explanation

```python
œȦDḣZ  # Implicit input
œ      # Filter the input by:
 Ȧ     #  Is alphanumeric?
  D    # Duplicate
   ḣ   # Remove the first item
    Z  # Zip them together
       # Join by spaces
       # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3) `S`, 4 bytes

```
/““o
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyJTIiwiIiwiL+KAnOKAnG8iLCIiLCJcIlRoaXMgaXMgX25vdF8gbGVnaWJsZVwiIiwiMy40LjIiXQ==)

janky formatting allows for a 3 byter