# Is the input Bl lu ur rr ry?

Tags: code-golf, string, decision-problem

This is based off [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/203893/bl-lu-ur-rr-ry-yv-vi-is-si-io-on-blur-the-text/) challenge.

Given an input string, check whether the string is blurry.

### What's a blurry string?

A blurry string is a string that's contained in the set of all blurrified pure-ASCII strings.

Take a non-blurrified pure-ASCII string `abc` as an example. You repeat every character of this twice:

```
aabbcc
```

And then insert spaces at every odd-even index.

```
a ab bc c
```

Then, remove the preceding 2 and succeeding 2 extra characters. If there isn't enough space left, ignore the abundant removing instructions.

```
ab bc
```

As an example, all of these strings are blurry (the empty line stands for an empty string):

```
Before  After
"a"   ->
"ab"  ->ab
"abc" ->ab bc
"abcd"->ab bc cd
...

(Before = the string before blurrification)
(After  = the string after blurrification,
i.e. the strings in the set of all blurry strings.)
```

### Specification

- The input string consists purely of printable ASCII characters. The only whitespace it will contain is the space character.
- You don't have to remove extra characters before the check.
- Your output can consist of any trailing whitespace, as long as it's possible to tell a truthy result from a falsy result.
- It's noteworthy that the definition of "blurry" in this challenge is **different** than the previous challenge.

### Test cases

[Here](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/a@kxKWUmAQmFJKSYbRCcgqQqYBgQkUVlLiAbDAfqhYkDFOinJSsDGUmJUMYCkjGATlgrgLIuqREheQkhZRkCBOoBMx0c0tMzMkpLk5NVeLS5Dq39f@hZYdWGB/ecm6r0bmdCcWHu4sPbwhUqz08/3/tfwA) is a program I use to check my test cases.

```
""          -> True
"ab"        -> True
"ab bc"     -> True
"aa aa"     -> True
"ab bc cd"  -> True
" b bc cd"  -> True
"ab bc c "  -> True
"a   c cd"  -> True
"        "  -> True

"a"         -> False
"abc"       -> False
"ab  bc  cd"-> False
"ab#bc#cd"  -> False
"abbccd"    -> False
"a ab bc cd"-> False
"a a ab b b"-> False
"ba cb dc"  -> False
"ba bc dc"  -> False
"FFaallssee"-> False
"a aa a"    -> False
```

Comment: I think it would be good to include some test cases where characters in the pre-blurred string repeat.

Comment: I meant truthy ones like `a aa a` or even just eight spaces. (Edit: Oops, I mean `aa aa`)

Comment: I'd argue the empty string is not blurry because one doesn't simply remove the first and last two characters from a string shorter than 4.

Comment: I don't understand how is `" b bc cd"` or `"ab bc c "` or `"a c cd"` or `""` or `" "*8` blurry. What are the strings that originated those?

Comment: Depending on the answer to my comment above, it might be good to edit the challenge to explicitly specify we are defining a blurry string in a way that is _different_ from what was done in the challenge in which this one is inspired

Comment: @RGS `" bcd"`, `"abc" `, `"a cd"` , `""` and `"    "` (4 spaces) respectively

Comment: @JoKing if you are right, then _"it might be good to edit the challenge to explicitly specify we are defining a blurry string in a way that is **different** from what was done in the challenge in which this one is inspired"_ (which should be done by the OP, not saying you should do it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) with `-plF/^(.((.)\x20\3)*.|)$/`, 7 bytes

```perl
$_=@F^1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzPCsIwDIfveYrAdmgFO//gUfDUpxiTJOtBKG5YDx58dmuzTsMP8iX5yBwe8ZRzez1f/LDPGYhLkAWIkKgyygj4g3WDQIhYT2uB6qKCGtVtWJoFWLTh/1/BZUAGJhTGURTKsYD3RDGmFIJ6JZ9pft6me8rbOfpuMM4YZ/vXYdcf7ca9bdt9AQ)

#### Explanation

Continuing the theme of abusing `-F`, I ended up with the same expression used in the Retina answer. The `-F` argument splits the input string on the valid expression and will place an even number of elements in `@F`, if the regular expression doesn't match, `@F` will just contain one entry, the whole string. When numeric operators are applied to a list (`@F` in this case) the length is implicitly used, so we XOR with 1 to give `0` for the failing test cases and a positive integer for all others.

Answer (score 7):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 14 bytes

```
a`.((.) \2)*.|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYxBCsJADEX3OcWHUpiKDOghegG3LvqTzqJQXFiX3n1MOq3hQ16SR97ls7x4q316TNfKKaeUBzzvwyV/axWqB2pCgmwMmwUnHBsIAbTTURK6hRBGczu1bge1aPj/c9wHqChhitkC/OgwjuS6blsp4Xl@)

## Explanation

`a` forces the match to be on the entire string

`.((.) \2)*.` just means any character (`.`) followed by a captured group repeated 0 to many times (`(...)*`) of any character saved into a second captured group (`(.)`) followed by a space and the same character that was matched in the second capture group (`\2`). The final `.` just matches the last character

`|` allows the empty string to match by having an alternative match of the empty string

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>60</s> 54 bytes

-6 bytes thanks to Surculose Sputum!

```python
a,*b,c=input()or'ab'
while b:x,y,z,*b=b;x[x!=z][y>' ']
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY1Ba8MwDIXv/hUaPTgdue2WkR4GzXG77FZ6kBRBQ0McVIfZ/fOpnaRlRqAnve/JY/QXN3zM7FqprbUzlu9Uct0N4@SLvVOLZM3fpesFqAplLO8JqOkznMJbfT@f4sGCPc8pajbsVyepDIDXmBuABOEif7BfxlG7wRf2q59Uo807CSyjh@NPc1R1uqZIBa8vs/of/XYeaIvPBikVEBtEQFw1cGvgKbYNGEwnVmt7JuOcgUys7I54twji3OB1L8llADKEwAQtZ5HMJJoGse9vN5HMpXoA) Output is via exit code.

By using different sets of errors for truthy/falsy inputs this can be [52 bytes](https://tio.run/##fYw9a8QwDIZ3/wqVG5yUbN1S0qFwgS7XpXQ5bpAUwYW6cfA51L4/n9pJ@rXUCPRIevyO0Z/tcDez7aTRWs9Y3VLFTT@Mky9K6yCoj3NvBKgOVayu6dzQfTiGm@Z6OsYHDfo0p49q017cJLUC8C7mBiBBuMjx5TKOrh98oR/N5FzUeSeBZfRwwHfZO2dd/b@3f25/aeQE336OxSuaaY2p4GnoJCxc/sk8WA@05c4KKRUQK0RAXBm4U/AF2wYUpoj1tD2Vdc5CNlZ3R7xbgDg3@M5LuAxAihCYoOMM6ZigbRGNuVxEspfqEw), as suggested by Surculose Sputum.

Comment: [55 bytes](https://tio.run/##fY4xT8QwDIX3/ApLN6RFlU6IrSgL4joeC2Jgs1Oji640lZtCe3@@JG3hYCGy5Ge/z0/ppnDy7d1sfc1Gaz1jcUOFNa7thpDlXmBUnyfXMFA5FlNxibah@9t9NhpzyffZZIwGnc/xVqma34BHFw9LBSDoeoYjvvNBxIvagp5l4GQHmVKDeME2Sx/Il7ET14ZMPzSDyKTTjkfLXbgmlf9zh6fqF0bCeL6a2SuLf3Qfrne@XbACXrAZ1uT8T/TRB6AtflZIsYCsQgTEVYOtFXyLbQMKY8RqbU8l3CYgESu7I7tbBNnU4CcvymUAUoRgCWqbRDSjqCrEpul75sTF@gI) by throwing `NameError` when input is empty.

Comment: [54 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY1Ba8MwDIXv/hUaPTgdue2WkR4GzXG77FZ6kBRBQ0McVIfZ/fOpnaRlRqAnve/JY/QXN3zM7FqprbUzlu9Uct0N4@SLvVOLZM3fpesFqAplLO8JqOkznMJbfT@f4sGCPc8pajbsVyepDIDXmBuABOEif7BfxlG7wRf2q59Uo807CSyjh@NPc1R1uqZIBa8vs/of/XYeaIvPBikVEBtEQFw1cGvgKbYNGEwnVmt7JuOcgUys7I54twji3OB1L8llADKEwAQtZ5HMJJoGse9vN5HMpXoA).

Comment: -1 byte: `x[x+y!=z+' ']`

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 57 bytes

```python
lambda x:x==''.join(c+' '+c for c in x[::3]+x[-1:])[2:-2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZFNboMwEIX3PsVoosggRNSmO0t0yQmyIyzGxqhEFBCmEj09tQklOGXZJ6@@@Xmeme57@Gib81Qm16mmT1kQjGJMEs5Pt7ZqAhVx4JGCsu1BQdXAmAnxlkdjFr@KPMzOIj7n09B/6Ys2g4EE0AlWxe9wsVGGJHGHgVT4xAiIcCcPVIEbBjtsyQOP2UZ/ahc9mP0zYyXVxpuDcDtH6sLOROEOBGftfLbwINXh13qFUs3Ig7CO6MEZg9xASaAkFMrraaEtfoJpSlTXxmjt97TPc7@Pbu9bufuupzyZrq6GgF8bHgoG0FE/76VaArYphpbrUasAu75qBiiDownxOKdmL3nI2J1jsmjr9Nj2f1hNPw)

Uses the same approach as my [Pyth answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/204259/65425). The blurring portion of the code is based off of [@Surculose Sputum's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203895/65425) to the original "Blur a string" challenge.

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 68 bytes

```hs
_#""=1<2
p#(' ':x:y:s)|p==x=y#s
_#_=2<1
f""=1<2
f(x:y:s)=y#s
f _=2<1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZBPa8MgGMbv@RQPemgCo9AeQ73s0OPYvYzwaswmc0nQtDSw754ZY0M6Efm9j@@fR7/If2trp6nijInD6Zj1PN9hV97LsfTFby/EXYzcZxWvxPF0yJqU1uRLRrxsEC@nHzItBOouA6weYPyrvTo3Bq1JUkPW6zf9SYO56Vk3dtAOedsN2K8FBS6MvYCRXE5IFYFAtCpQ9czYcNIRGcCakxb72Np477x5trEavrA0R6W2c991CJeKP1iqRNiaClGMER8gCUqiVolD1sLnM5G13mudasKOFntn2n9/9aw@rAfV6eHqWuRF4OkP)

### Explanation

`f` is the entry point. No real tricks; loop through recursively ensuring that every third character is a space, while keeping track of the second character of the previous chunk each time and ensuring that it's equal to the first of the next chunk.

Comment: You can combine the first and last case for both `(#)` and `f`.  [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZDBasQgFEX3@YqLLiYDQz8g4KaLWZbuw1CexrRSm4SYlgT676kxbyRTETken3r1g8Kn9X5dB1mecKrmaqnC@XdQalaLDMWbnCOp@la05b6WdAvW6xe5DgpNXwDeTnDh2X@P4xJdy6olH@yLfafJ/djNOz/ZEWXXT3jKG86ohbhAkN5HaJOAQJQNTLMxDsweiQHkGm7idozx2gf3GCMHrgXfY/jY7dx8idRG3lkbJhxDxVmaIz1AE4xGY5hj1c7XK5H3IVjLe2JPEYfRdf/@6tHeo0e7/gE "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 13 bytes

```
qjd.:+%3Q>1Q2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/vzArRc9KW9U40M4w0Oj/f6XEJIWkZIXkFCUA)

```
qjd.:+%3Q>1Q2
      %3Q      Take every 3rd character of the input string
                (eg. "ab bc cd" becomes "abc")
     +   >1Q   Append the last character of the input string
 jd.:       2  "Blur" the resulting string 
                (ie. find all substrings of length 2 and join on spaces)
q              Return true if that matches the input string
```

Comment: For -1 byte, `>1Q` is the same as `eQ`

Comment: @ar4093 Yep, except that `eQ` throws an Index Out of Range error for the empty string :/

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>16</s> <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
¤º«3ô€нüJðýQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Wqa6kd3iHvZKCrp2Ckn2ly/9DSw7tOrTa@PCWR01rLuw9vMfr8IbDewP/6/yPVlLSUUpMAhMKSckgOlEhMRHGV0hOATIVEEyoqAKIqaCgAFMABUo6CkoQvckQtSDFMI3KScnKUGZSMoShgGQJkAPmKoAck5SokJykkJIMYQKVgJlubomJOTnFxampEPVApBQLAA)

Uses the blurring program [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203906/78850) to re-blur the string. -1 byte thanks to Kevin Cruijssen!

### Old Answer Explained

```
3ô`©)€н`®θJüJðýQ
3ô                  # Split the input into chunks of 3
  `©                # Item split the above and store the last item in the register
    )               # Wrap everything back into a list
     €н             # Get the first character from each item in then above list
       `            # Item split the list generated from the above map
        ®θJ         # Join the above with the last letter from the register
           üJðý     # Blatant port of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203906/78850 -- i.e. blur the string
               Q    # Check to see if the blurred string is the input
```

Comment: -1 by changing ``3ô€н`IθJ`` to `¤º«3ô€н`: [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Wqa6kd3iHvZKCrp2Ckn2ly/9DSw7tOrTa@PCWR01rLuw9vMfr8IbDewP/6/yPVlLSUUpMAhMKSckgOlEhMRHGV0hOATIVEEyoqAKIqaCgAFMABUo6CkoQvckQtSDFMI3KScnKUGZSMoShgGQJkAPmKoAck5SokJykkJIMYQKVgJlubomJOTnFxampEPVApBQLAA).

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>26</s> 21 bytes

```
⁼✂θ¹±¹¦¹⭆✂θ¹±¹¦³⁺⁺ι ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMO1sDQxp1gjOCczOVWjUEfBUEfBLzU9sSRVw1ATyAPi4BKgwnTfxAJcioyBOCCntFgDTGTqKCgpKAGFMjVBwPr//0QFBYVkheQUrv@6ZTkA) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs a Charcoal boolean, `-` for a blurry string, nothing if not. Explanation:

```
  θ                     Input string
 ✂ ¹±¹¦¹                Slice off the first and last characters
⁼                       Is equal to
          θ             Input string
         ✂ ¹±¹¦³        Every other third character
        ⭆               Map over characters and join
                ⁺⁺ι ι   Wrap a space in that character
                        Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 13 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

The empty string being truthy cost a couple of bytes :\

```
¶¬ë3 pUÌ ä+ ¸
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=tqzrMyBwVcwg5CsguA&footer=V2dWIPpBICsiID0gIitV&input=WyIiLCAiYWIiLCAiYWIgYmMiLCAiYWEgYWEiLCAiYWIgYmMgY2QiLCAiIGIgYmMgY2QiLCAiYWIgYmMgYyAiLCAiYSAgIGMgY2QiLCAiICAgICAgICAiLCAiYSIsICJhYmMiLCAiYWIgIGJjICBjZCIsICJhYiNiYyNjZCIsICJhYmJjY2QiLCAiYSBhYiBiYyBjZCIsICJhIGEgYWIgYiBiIiwgImJhIGNiIGRjIiwgImJhIGJjIGRjIiwgIkZGYWFsbHNzZWUiLCAiYSBhYSBhIl0KLW1S) (includes all test cases)

```
¶¬ë3 pUÌ ä+ ¸     :Implicit input of string U
¶                 :Test for equality with
 ¬                :Split to an array
  ë3              :Take every 3rd element, starting with the first
     p            :Push
      UÌ          :  Last character of U
         ä+       :Consecutive pairs, reduced by concatenation
            ¸     :Join with spaces
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <s>52</s> 51 bytes

```
func[a][s:[skip]parse a[opt[s any[copy t s" "t]s]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZAxDsIwDEX3nuIrzAwwdmDkAKxWBsdJBaK0UR2Gnr4EaNqCFSV@tn@U/CH46RI82aqpMTXPTogtaU16v0UbedAApj4mUnA3kvRxRIIamGTVWjs1/RBYrkhBE6hCDmO@B7slgZOSM5i3dYifEb84d1Ewb9vhOUp3Eckqf@u39@2c7DboZAX8vSUXPiWUPziGOHhZMY8veD4zt61qCKs@L1NZisOty85E9nj0rf8adTjC7E@m@VB28QU)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
m3żḊ$K⁼Ṗ
```

A monadic Link accepting a list of characters which yields `1` (blurry), or `0` (not blurry).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/X@Oiehzu6VLwfNe55uHPa////lRIVFBSSFZJTlAA)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/X@Oiehzu6VLwfNe55uHPa/6N7Drc/alrjDcSR//9HKylx6SglJkFIhaRkMCNRITERLqKQnAJiKyCxoeIKYLaCggJcDRSAxSEKk6HqQRrgupWTkpVh7KRkKEsB2TYgD8xXALssKVEhOUkhJRnKBqqCsN3cEhNzcoqLU1OheoBIiSsWAA).

#### How?

```
m3żḊ$K⁼Ṗ - Link: list of characters, S
m3       - modulo-3-slice (S)
    $    - last two links as a monad (f(X)):
   Ḋ     -   remove the head (X)
  ż      -   zip together (X and that)
     K   - join with spaces
       Ṗ - remove the tail (S)
      ⁼  - equal?
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 29 bytes

```javascript
s=>/^.((.) \2)*.$|^$/.test(s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5BC4MwDIXv/RUBPbSba2HXsR39FUNMY5WNYsXITvvvLtVt8CBf3gvhPfGFTPNjWk5j6sLaX1e@3lxjtbYG7mdzsOW7KZ1dAi@azXqBVqEXgSeFCIg7A3UKfvB1QCEA7I54lP0c7CeFp2IDT3nA/43gtoBXHoE8dJRBQoG6RoyROYR8J1KtncMUkYJ29uiGSvpTGjnFYGMaNFfQS3Fj1g8)

Pure port